Avro Schema issue with array union
I am using below definition in my AVRO schema registered on Kafka topic
{
  "doc": "list of employees",
  "name": "employees",
  "type": [
    "null",
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "avro.java.string": "String",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  ],
  "default": null
}

Expected output:
"employees" : ["Ajay", "Vijay"] OR null
But getting below one:
 "employees": {
      "array": [
        "Ajay", "Vijay"
      ]
    }

I checked with this below schema its working fine. if i am adding default null so its creating extra array field
{
  "doc": "list of employees",
  "name": "employees",
  "type":
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "avro.java.string": "String",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  
}


The way you are specifying the field employees (as a union type) is making Avro add the extra wrapper around your field, and leaving it the way you see it.
What you can do is initialize the field directly as an empty array ([]) instead of declaring the default array as null. This way, you will have a similar behavior to the current one without that extra nesting.
This is how your schema should look like:
{
  "doc": "list of employees",
  "name": "employees",
  "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": "string"
  },
  "default": []
}


If employees null then it creating issue on confluent validation

If handling null is essential, you might consider handling it programmatically where the data is processed.

What I mean is that if you want to use null directly then you will have to accept the extra wrapping when serializing the array, or you can use the empty array as default and manage the null logic in your application.

@Himanshu Please edit your question to clarify what errors you're seeing. Otherwise, read the arvo docs on "JSON encoding" to understand why this wrapper is added

not getting error but result should be Expected output:
"employees" : ["Ajay", "Vijay"] OR null
But getting below one:
"employees": {
"array": [
"Ajay", "Vijay"
]
}

for now i managed with mandatory schema when sending data passing empty array to the topic then it is working. but client need not manipulation before sending data whenever register schema
